# Powershell SharePoint 2010 capture Permissions of folders in library with Broken Inheritance

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, powershell, permissions, folder

I am looking for some code to find all users or Ad Group who have some sort of permission in specific folder (with broken Permission) in a specific library of a team-site. With the following code I can find all the folder within a library that has unique permission (Broken Inheritance)

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL #$($SiteIdentity.Url)
Write-Host "Site: " $web.Title
#$list = $web.Lists["Shared Documents"] 
$list = $web.GetList($web.Url +"/Documents/")
write-host "Library Title: "$list.Title
$list.Folders  | ft Name, HasUniqueRoleAssignments, Folder
```

But not getting the list of users/AD group those have some sort of(read , contrib etc) permission on that specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will get a list of the users on folders in a specific library.

```
function getUsersAndPerm($web){
  $UsersOnFolders = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  foreach($List in $web.Lists){
     if($List.Title -eq "YOUR LIST TITLE"){
        foreach($folder in $List.Folders){

           foreach($user in $folder.RoleAssignments){

               $UserName = $user.Member.LoginName

               foreach($role in $user.RoleDefinitionBindings){
                   if( $role.Name -eq "Administrators" ){
                       $UsersOnFolders.Add("$UserName,Administrators")
                       break                          
                   }
                   elseif( $role.Name -eq "Contributors" ){
                        $UsersOnFolders.Add("$UserName,Contributors")                          
                   }
                   elseif( $role.Name -eq "Read"){
                       $UsersOnFolders.Add("$UserName,Read")                           
                   }
               }
          }
      }
  }
  return $UsersOnFolders
 }
```